# firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword webapp Authorized Domain

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase Build: 3.2.0-rc.2,
AngularFire 1.2.0,
AngularJS v1.3.15,
From this tutorial page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

I have this problem where using firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword fails when I put my Angularjs project on my remote host, but on my localhost everything works fine.

I even put my domain mydomainname.com inside firebase console > Sign-in method > Authorized domains and it still doesn't work. I've also tried uploading my project to firebase as the host under the same project and adding that domain in Authorized domains, same problem!

I know the code works, because the same code works running on my local machine, the only error is some cross domain trust error. I've read that there is this problem in Android using ionic , but I'm doing a webapp is there a similar issue???

Not there there is an issue with the code/setup from what I can see, but I'll post it anyway:

Firebase rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      //".read": "true",
      //".write": "true"
    ".read": "$uid==='my_uid_from_user_users_section'",
    ".write": "$uid==='my_uid_from_user_users_section'"
    },
  }
}
```

AngularJS signin Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngRoute',
  'vcRecaptcha',
  "firebase"
]);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user,password).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log("login failed errorCode: " + errorCode);
  console.log("login failed errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
              console.log("logged in:" + user.uid);
            });
            } else {
                console.log("error failed to log in");
            }
});
```

I get "error failed to log in" when it is hosted.
Testing on localhost yields "logged in "

Is the free tier not allowed to use these features?? Or what am I doing wrong here? Kind of frustrating.

Comment: You are following the quick start for Firebase 2.x, but are using Firebase 3.x. I recommend using the [updated quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md)

Comment: I'm not understanding how using firebase.auth() and getting permission exceptions has anything to do with using the angulareFire wrappers. I'm not using them in my calls. I'm using firebase.auth() directly. That should work.. I've updated to use angularjs/1.5.8 , angularfire/2.0.1, and firebasejs/3.3.0. Still doesn't work. It works on my local machine fine that is the puzzling part. I wonder if it is because firebase bans some webhosts? I'm testing on a free host like 000webhost.com, but even on paid hosts like 1&1 it still wasn't working.

Comment: And yes... I've already added those domains to Authorized domain section under Auth in firebase.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that it does work, it's just that my service call wasn't getting the signin execution. Once i put the signin process into my controller then it works...

Comment: That's great to hear!